# What is meant by a "clean object model"?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, quantlib

I've heard systems described as a "clean object model", but a precise definition does not seem to be around.  It seems to refer to the classes being complete or consistent in some way.

I'm just wondering if it's referring to a specific trait or just another favorable term like 'elegant'.

Quantlib is described as "written in C++ with a clean object model".[1](http://quantlib.org)

Comment: I've removed a few tags that were seemingly irrelevant. If they are, could you specify how this specifically applies to them? Could you also reference sources so we can see the context? As a sidenote: this might be more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should leave C++ and QuantLib, I would think.  From the first page of the Quantlib.org website: "QuantLib is written in C++ with a clean object model..."

Comment: Can you add all your references (such as that) in your question then? I still very much doubt whether they are appropriate tags.

Comment: I doubt there exists a clean definition.  It means "I think my objects are well designed from an API point of view."

Comment: The Ruby people use the term as well.

Comment: It's opposite of a "dirty object model".

Comment: Everybody writes highly modular code with a crispy clean object model.  Lasts about a year, give or take.  A month if it is agile.

Comment: Hans is not wrong. The copy on the QuantLib site was written a _long_ time ago.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio, you would know!  :)

Comment: I disagree that this is 'opinion-based'.  It is a description used by writers to describe code that purports a particular meaning.  I also cite: http://www.fantasy-coders.de/ruby/ruby_1.html which states: "very clean object model; there are (almost) no exceptions to it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a technical term. A "clean" object model is a well-designed one, by whichever standard of good design. Usually it involved orthogonal classes with a clear separation of concerns and an intuitive mapping to real-world concepts, i.e. a lot of fuzziness that you'll need to judge for yourself.

Comment: I'll go with this answer before it closes.....